# ASP.NET Core 5 Response Json and Input JSON encoding issue

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have the following API,

```
    public class MyApiClass
    {
        public string Str { get; set; }
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("myApi", Name = "MyApi2")]
    public IActionResult MyApi(MyApiClass myClassInput)
    {
        var obj = new MyApiClass
        {
            Str = "h24KFS69\\pucBJH3x2ov+MAj\\/JWq/UBt3EjhKGUtBM="
        };
        return Ok(obj);
    }
```

I will call this API in Postman I will get the below response,

```
{
    "str": "h24KFS69\\pucBJH3x2ov+MAj\/JWq/UBt3EjhKGUtBM="
}
```

Then I will call the same API using the same but as input,

```
{
    "str": "h24KFS69\\pucBJH3x2ov+MAj\/JWq/UBt3EjhKGUtBM="
}
```

Then I checked,

```
>>> myClassInput.Str
"h24KFS69\\pucBJH3x2ov+MAj/JWq/UBt3EjhKGUtBM="
>>> obj.Str
"h24KFS69\\pucBJH3x2ov+MAj\\/JWq/UBt3EjhKGUtBM="
>>> myClassInput.Str == obj.Str
false
```

I am sending whatever I am getting in JSON response. Why they are different strings?

Interestingly, if you peak both values,

[image]

[image]

and test in JS,

```
>>> "h24KFS69\pucBJH3x2ov+MAj\/JWq/UBt3EjhKGUtBM=" === "h24KFS69\pucBJH3x2ov+MAj/JWq/UBt3EjhKGUtBM="
true
```

Comment: Feels like the escape sequence `\/` is treated exactly the same as a single `/`` since it doesn't usually need escaping in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that PostMan have pretty and raw response modes.

Pretty mode converting,

```
{
    "str": "h24KFS69\\pucBJH3x2ov+MAj\\/JWq/UBt3EjhKGUtBM="
}
```

into

```
{
    "str": "h24KFS69\\pucBJH3x2ov+MAj\/JWq/UBt3EjhKGUtBM="
}
```

I needed to use Raw mode.

Filed an issue with Postman as well https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/11307

Answer (score 0):

In your API method try to make the string verbatim:

> Str = @"h24KFS69\pucBJH3x2ov+MAj\/JWq/UBt3EjhKGUtBM="